# Choose application.properties file via command line

Tags: java, spring-boot, command-line, properties, spring-data

I'm developing a command line Spring Boot Application, and I need Spring to load his configurations (DB URLs, users, etc), not necessarily from the default application.properties file, but on a .properties file specified in the String[] args parameter. I may use some hints about how this could be implemented. 
Thanks for your time.

Comment: Have you read about externalized configuration in the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html ?

Comment: @JoachimRohde  first thing, thank you. Second, 24.3 (not sure if that was the point you meant to bring up to me) seems to offer a way to achieve my goal (by specifying the name and/or the location of a different props file), so I may give it a try. However, there are more different domain related aspects that may influence the properties than just the profile, and I would have preferred them to be added in the process via command line and elaborated by the java code, resulting in a 'ad-hoc' properties file choice (possibly with no need for the app user to know about properties file location).

Answer (score 1):

This can be done via the spring.config.location property.

In your command line you would add the

```
-Dspring.config.location=C:/application.properties (or whatever the path may be).
```

This will then replace any properties file you have in your spring boot application and you can alter it at will at run time.

Comment: That's exactly the workaround I applied after @JoachimRohde posted the link of the documentation. However, I would prefer to "hide" the application.config logic to the user, providing some sort of "options" related to the business logic (-option1 value1 -option2 value2). I assume that a way to do that is parsing the arguments and use them to choose the actual properties file. I hope I explained myself now. Thank you for your involvement.

Comment: Ah I understand. Well in that case the best way to do that would be to use spring shell to call your jar with the options you require. You can have whatever options you would like then: https://projects.spring.io/spring-shell/. Alternatively you could create a bash script to do the same, simply mapping option1 to your relevant application.properties file.